# Unserialize PHP Array in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a table with a load of rows of serialized arrays that I plan to request and pass it to `JavaScript`.

The problem is - is it possible to `unserialize` with JavaScript rather than PHP ?

Otherwise I will have to load all the rows, loop them and unserialize them and assign them to a temporary PHP array and then json_encode it back to JavaScript which seems highly inefficient if I can send the data still serialized so that JavaScript can unserialize the data when it needs to.

Is there a built in Javascript function that does it or will I have to loop the rows in PHP before I encode it?

Note I am not using jQuery.

EDIT:
Example of my serialized data in PHP from my table:

```
a:8:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:10;i:1;i:11;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:9;i:1;i:11;}i:2;a:2:
{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:11;}i:3;a:2:{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:10;}i:4;a:2:{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:9;}i:5;a:2:
{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:8;}i:6;a:2:{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:7;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:6;}}
```

Comment: Can you use json_encode instead of serialize? That may be easier to work with when communicating between PHP and JS. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I serialize the arrays before i store them into my database so i can store it and save space. I don't think json_encode would do the job.

Comment: @Dave But you can unserialize in PHP and then JSON encode.

Comment: Maybe unserialize after retrieval and then send as json?  Also, serialization adds a fair amount of extra data so you may not be saving much space in the long run.

Comment: So my only choice is to loop ALL the rows i select to unserialize the specific fields then encode a temp array with that data? Thats very inefficient :(

Comment: If you're going through all that trouble, you may want to look at your database/application design.

Comment: You need to *loop* through the rows anyway. A bit of unserializing-Json-encoding doesn't hurt that much. And tough luck if you choose a bad storage format to begin with. :P

Comment: i always thought serialize was the best? What others are there :P

Comment: Serialized PHP is only readable by PHP (for the most part). That's not exactly a great storage format for data in a database. At least you should store it in a language neutral format like JSON; depending on your database there may even be native support for JSON encoded data in the database. Best though is to normalize the data into tables and columns. If you store serialized data you should have a good reason to do so.

Comment: json_encode is a form of serialized data. Just use json_encode/json_decode. No need to even bother with serialized data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wrap `json_encode` around `unserialize`

```
echo json_encode( unserialize( $array));
```

Comment: What if i'm selecting multiple rows from a table with such data?

Comment: then you need to push all the rows into another array and send the full array

Comment: Damn thats what i was hoping to avoid for performance reasons

Comment: `performace reasons`? How much different is it than looping over rows to generate other output such as html, or creating arrays of json from fields?

Comment: well if JS was doing it - it would be based on the hardware of the user's pc not my server hardware which would be doing it constantly from all the visitors etc.

Comment: json_encode/decode() and un/serialize() should not be bottlenecks unless dealing with a great many large arrays or objects (as in many mbs when encoded).

Answer (score 18):

Php.js has javascript implementations of unserialize and serialize:

http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/

That said, it's probably more efficient to convert to JSON on the server side. JSON.parse is going to be a lot faster than PHP.js's unserialize.

Comment: Entire website seems dead: {"detail":"Not Found"}

Comment: Github still seems to have the source https://github.com/hirak/phpjs

Answer (score 15):

I thought I would have a go at writing a JS function that can unserialize PHP-serialized data.

But before going for this solution please be aware that:

- The format produced by PHP's `serialize` function is PHP specific and so the best option is to use PHP's `unserialize` to have 100% guarantee that it is doing the job right.
- PHP can store class information in those strings and even the output of some custom serialization methods. So to unserialize such strings you would need to know about those classes and methods.
- PHP data structures do not correspond 1-to-1 to JavaScript data structures: PHP associative arrays can have strings as keys, and so they look more like JavaScript objects than JS arrays, but in PHP the keys keep insertion order, and keys can have a truly numeric data type which is not possible with JS objects. One could say that then we should look at `Map` objects in JS, but those allow to store 13 and "13" as separate keys, which PHP does not allow. And we're only touching the tip of the iceberg here...
- PHP serializes protected and private properties of objects, which not only is strange (how *private* is that?), but are concepts which do not (yet) exist in JS, or at least not in the same way. If one would somehow implement (hard) private properties in JS, then how would some unserialization be *able* to *set* such a private property?
- JSON is an alternative that is not specific to PHP, and does not care about custom classes either. If you can access the PHP source of were the serialization happens, then change this to produce JSON instead. PHP offers `json_encode` for that, and JavaScript has `JSON.parse` to decode it. This is certainly the way to go if you can.

If with those remarks you still see the need for a JS unserialise function, then read on.

Here is a JS implementation that provides a `PHP` object with similar methods as the built-in `JSON` object: `parse` and `stringify`.

When an input to the `parse` method references a class, then it will first check if you passed a reference to that class in the (optional) second argument. If not, a mock will be created for that class (to avoid undesired side-effects). In either case an instance of that class will be created. If the input string specifies a *custom* serialization happened then the method `unserialize` on that object instance will be called. You must provide the logic in that method as the string itself does not give information about how that should be done. It is only known in the PHP code that *generated* that string.

This implementation also supports cyclic references. When an associative array turns out to be a sequential array, then a JS array will be returned.

```js
const PHP = {
    stdClass: function() {},
    stringify(val) {
        const hash = new Map([[Infinity, "d:INF;"], [-Infinity, "d:-INF;"], [NaN, "d:NAN;"], [null, "N;"], [undefined, "N;"]]); 
        const utf8length = str => str ? encodeURI(str).match(/(%.)?./g).length : 0;
        const serializeString = (s,delim='"') => `${utf8length(s)}:${delim[0]}${s}${delim[delim.length-1]}`;
        let ref = 0;
        
        function serialize(val, canReference = true) {
            if (hash.has(val)) return hash.get(val);
            ref += canReference;
            if (typeof val === "string") return `s:${serializeString(val)};`;
            if (typeof val === "number") return  `${Math.round(val) === val ? "i" : "d"}:${(""+val).toUpperCase().replace(/(-?\d)E/, "$1.0E")};`;
            if (typeof val === "boolean") return  `b:${+val};`;
            const a = Array.isArray(val) || val.constructor === Object;
            hash.set(val, `${"rR"[+a]}:${ref};`);
            if (typeof val.serialize === "function") {
                return `C:${serializeString(val.constructor.name)}:${serializeString(val.serialize(), "{}")}`;
            }
            const vals = Object.entries(val).filter(([k, v]) => typeof v !== "function");
            return (a ? "a" : `O:${serializeString(val.constructor.name)}`) 
                + `:${vals.length}:{${vals.map(([k, v]) => serialize(a && /^\d{1,16}$/.test(k) ? +k : k, false) + serialize(v)).join("")}}`;
        }
        return serialize(val);
    },
    // Provide in second argument the classes that may be instantiated
    //  e.g.  { MyClass1, MyClass2 }
    parse(str, allowedClasses = {}) {
        allowedClasses.stdClass = PHP.stdClass; // Always allowed.
        let offset = 0;
        const values = [null];
        const specialNums = { "INF": Infinity, "-INF": -Infinity, "NAN": NaN };

        const kick = (msg, i = offset) => { throw new Error(`Error at ${i}: ${msg}\n${str}\n${" ".repeat(i)}^`) }
        const read = (expected, ret) => expected === str.slice(offset, offset+=expected.length) ? ret 
                                         : kick(`Expected '${expected}'`, offset-expected.length);
        
        function readMatch(regex, msg, terminator=";") {
            read(":");
            const match = regex.exec(str.slice(offset));
            if (!match) kick(`Exected ${msg}, but got '${str.slice(offset).match(/^[:;{}]|[^:;{}]*/)[0]}'`);
            offset += match[0].length;
            return read(terminator, match[0]);
        }
        
        function readUtf8chars(numUtf8Bytes, terminator="") {
            const i = offset;
            while (numUtf8Bytes > 0) {
                const code = str.charCodeAt(offset++);
                numUtf8Bytes -= code < 0x80 ? 1 : code < 0x800 || code>>11 === 0x1B ? 2 : 3;
            }
            return numUtf8Bytes ? kick("Invalid string length", i-2) : read(terminator, str.slice(i, offset));
        }
        
        const create = className => !className ? {}
                    : allowedClasses[className] ? Object.create(allowedClasses[className].prototype)
                    : new {[className]: function() {} }[className]; // Create a mock class for this name
        const readBoolean = () => readMatch(/^[01]/, "a '0' or '1'", ";");
        const readInt     = () => +readMatch(/^-?\d+/, "an integer", ";");
        const readUInt    = terminator => +readMatch(/^\d+/, "an unsigned integer", terminator);
        const readString  = (terminator="") => readUtf8chars(readUInt(':"'), '"'+terminator);
        
        function readDecimal() {
            const num = readMatch(/^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?(E[+-]\d+)?|INF)|NAN/, "a decimal number", ";");
            return num in specialNums ? specialNums[num] : +num;
        }
        
        function readKey() {
            const typ = str[offset++];
            return typ === "s" ? readString(";") 
                 : typ === "i" ? readUInt(";")
                 : kick("Expected 's' or 'i' as type for a key, but got ${str[offset-1]}", offset-1);
        }
       
        function readObject(obj) {
            for (let i = 0, length = readUInt(":{"); i < length; i++) obj[readKey()] = readValue();
            return read("}", obj);
        }
        
        function readArray() {
            const obj = readObject({});
            return Object.keys(obj).some((key, i) => key != i) ? obj : Object.values(obj);
        }
        
        function readCustomObject(obj) {
            if (typeof obj.unserialize !== "function") kick(`Instance of ${obj.constructor.name} does not have an "unserialize" method`);
            obj.unserialize(readUtf8chars(readUInt(":{")));
            return read("}", obj);
        }
        
        function readValue() {
            const typ = str[offset++].toLowerCase();
            const ref = values.push(null)-1;
            const val = typ === "n" ? read(";", null)
                      : typ === "s" ? readString(";")
                      : typ === "b" ? readBoolean()
                      : typ === "i" ? readInt()
                      : typ === "d" ? readDecimal()
                      : typ === "a" ? readArray()                            // Associative array
                      : typ === "o" ? readObject(create(readString()))       // Object
                      : typ === "c" ? readCustomObject(create(readString())) // Custom serialized object
                      : typ === "r" ? values[readInt()]                      // Backreference
                      : kick(`Unexpected type ${typ}`, offset-1);
            if (typ !== "r") values[ref] = val;
            return val;
        }
        
        const val = readValue();
        if (offset !== str.length) kick("Unexpected trailing character");
        return val;
    }
}
/**************** EXAMPLE USES ************************/

// Unserialize a sequential array
console.log(PHP.parse('a:4:{i:0;s:4:"This";i:1;s:2:"is";i:2;s:2:"an";i:3;s:5:"array";}'));

// Unserialize an associative array into an object
console.log(PHP.parse('a:2:{s:8:"language";s:3:"PHP";s:7:"version";d:7.1;}'));

// Example with class that has custom serialize function:
var MyClass = (function () {
    const priv = new WeakMap(); // This is a way to implement private properties in ES6
    return class MyClass {
        constructor() {
            priv.set(this, "");
            this.wordCount = 0;
        }
        unserialize(serialised) {
            const words = PHP.parse(serialised);
            priv.set(this, words);
            this.wordCount = words.split(" ").length;
        }
        serialize() {
            return PHP.stringify(priv.get(this));
        }
    }
})();

// Unserialise a PHP string that needs the above class to work, and will call its unserialize method
// The class needs to be passed as object key/value as second argument, so to allow this side effect to happen:
console.log(PHP.parse('C:7:"MyClass":23:{s:15:"My private data";}', { MyClass } ));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Just noticed your comment so here we go:

in PHP

```
json_encode(unserialize(SerializedVal));
```

in JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(JsonString);
```

Comment: when PHP serializes we cannot parse/unserialize it with javascript json parse. And irony is all SO questions has same answers JSON.parse.