# How to convert serialized PHP object to string JAVASCRIPT when I haven't access to PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php

**Hello Guys.**
This is my situation: I haven't access to PHP code, just result from serialized php object

I'd like know how to convert this:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:3:"200";i:2;s:3:"300";}
```

to this string with white spaces:

```
100 200 300
```

I'm using JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)

Thank you guys.

Comment: This should help you find the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227388/unserialize-php-array-in-javascript

Comment: In my case, I do not have access to the PHP code. Information is serialized and stored in the database and then is passed to javascript in serialized format. I can't use php functions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a result of PHP [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize). There's a [JS implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/) of PHP
s [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php).

```
function unserialize (data) {
  // From: http://phpjs.org/functions
  // +     original by: Arpad Ray (mailto:arpad@php.net)
  // +     improved by: Pedro Tainha (http://www.pedrotainha.com)
  // +     bugfixed by: dptr1988
  // +      revised by: d3x
  // +     improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +        input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +     improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +     improved by: Chris
  // +     improved by: James
  // +        input by: Martin (http://www.erlenwiese.de/)
  // +     bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +     improved by: Le Torbi
  // +     input by: kilops
  // +     bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +      input by: Jaroslaw Czarniak
  // +     improved by: Eli Skeggs
  // %            note: We feel the main purpose of this function should be to ease the transport of data between php & js
  // %            note: Aiming for PHP-compatibility, we have to translate objects to arrays
  // *       example 1: unserialize('a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Kevin";i:1;s:3:"van";i:2;s:9:"Zonneveld";}');
  // *       returns 1: ['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld']
  // *       example 2: unserialize('a:3:{s:9:"firstName";s:5:"Kevin";s:7:"midName";s:3:"van";s:7:"surName";s:9:"Zonneveld";}');
  // *       returns 2: {firstName: 'Kevin', midName: 'van', surName: 'Zonneveld'}
  var that = this,
    utf8Overhead = function (chr) {
      // http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571#comment_95906
      var code = chr.charCodeAt(0);
      if (code < 0x0080) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (code < 0x0800) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 2;
    },
    error = function (type, msg, filename, line) {
      throw new that.window[type](msg, filename, line);
    },
    read_until = function (data, offset, stopchr) {
      var i = 2, buf = [], chr = data.slice(offset, offset + 1);

      while (chr != stopchr) {
        if ((i + offset) > data.length) {
          error('Error', 'Invalid');
        }
        buf.push(chr);
        chr = data.slice(offset + (i - 1), offset + i);
        i += 1;
      }
      return [buf.length, buf.join('')];
    },
    read_chrs = function (data, offset, length) {
      var i, chr, buf;

      buf = [];
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        chr = data.slice(offset + (i - 1), offset + i);
        buf.push(chr);
        length -= utf8Overhead(chr);
      }
      return [buf.length, buf.join('')];
    },
    _unserialize = function (data, offset) {
      var dtype, dataoffset, keyandchrs, keys, contig,
        length, array, readdata, readData, ccount,
        stringlength, i, key, kprops, kchrs, vprops,
        vchrs, value, chrs = 0,
        typeconvert = function (x) {
          return x;
        };

      if (!offset) {
        offset = 0;
      }
      dtype = (data.slice(offset, offset + 1)).toLowerCase();

      dataoffset = offset + 2;

      switch (dtype) {
        case 'i':
          typeconvert = function (x) {
            return parseInt(x, 10);
          };
          readData = read_until(data, dataoffset, ';');
          chrs = readData[0];
          readdata = readData[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 1;
          break;
        case 'b':
          typeconvert = function (x) {
            return parseInt(x, 10) !== 0;
          };
          readData = read_until(data, dataoffset, ';');
          chrs = readData[0];
          readdata = readData[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 1;
          break;
        case 'd':
          typeconvert = function (x) {
            return parseFloat(x);
          };
          readData = read_until(data, dataoffset, ';');
          chrs = readData[0];
          readdata = readData[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 1;
          break;
        case 'n':
          readdata = null;
          break;
        case 's':
          ccount = read_until(data, dataoffset, ':');
          chrs = ccount[0];
          stringlength = ccount[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 2;

          readData = read_chrs(data, dataoffset + 1, parseInt(stringlength, 10));
          chrs = readData[0];
          readdata = readData[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 2;
          if (chrs != parseInt(stringlength, 10) && chrs != readdata.length) {
            error('SyntaxError', 'String length mismatch');
          }
          break;
        case 'a':
          readdata = {};

          keyandchrs = read_until(data, dataoffset, ':');
          chrs = keyandchrs[0];
          keys = keyandchrs[1];
          dataoffset += chrs + 2;

          length = parseInt(keys, 10);
          contig = true;

          for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            kprops = _unserialize(data, dataoffset);
            kchrs = kprops[1];
            key = kprops[2];
            dataoffset += kchrs;

            vprops = _unserialize(data, dataoffset);
            vchrs = vprops[1];
            value = vprops[2];
            dataoffset += vchrs;

            if (key !== i)
              contig = false;

            readdata[key] = value;
          }

          if (contig) {
            array = new Array(length);
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
              array[i] = readdata[i];
            readdata = array;
          }

          dataoffset += 1;
          break;
        default:
          error('SyntaxError', 'Unknown / Unhandled data type(s): ' + dtype);
          break;
      }
      return [dtype, dataoffset - offset, typeconvert(readdata)];
    }
  ;

  return _unserialize((data + ''), 0)[2];
}
```

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/ this website is a great resource for js ports of php funtions for your future referance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a replacement of unserialization algorithm, but a quick an dirty way to parse out enquoted portions of string.

```
'{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:3:"200";i:2;s:3:"300";}'.replace(/[^"]+;[^"]+/g, '').replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '').split('""');
```

Produces:

```
["100", "200", "300"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Lex Podgorny,

I made a little modification and it's works fine for me now:

'{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:3:"200";i:2;s:3:"300";}'.replace(/[^"]+:|;[^"]+/g, '').replace(/^"*|"*$/g, '').replace(/\"/g, " ");

This produce:   100 200 300