# PHP serialize data Unserialize using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to iterate below `serialized` data using `jQuery`

```
a:2:{i:0;s:8:"member 1";i:1;s:8:"member 2";}
```

Comment: The data you've shown isn't serialised at all - it's just an object (although with syntax problems due to the `;`). Assuming you have actual JSON data, then you can just use `JSON.parse` to turn it back in to an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unserialize PHP Array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227388/unserialize-php-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fetch serialized object using PHP, Why do you need php serialized object unserialize through jQuery only.

you can simply convert it into json serialize in PHP

```
ob_clean();
echo json_encode(unserialize($serialized_string));
die();
```

In jQuery you can use AJAX dataType when the response is not set as JSON

```
var obj= JSON.parse(response_from_server);
```