# how to unserialize data an ArrayObject in react

Tags: reactjs

Input

```
a:4:{s:13:"movie_release";s:10:"2020-01-10";s:14:"movie_duration";s:3:"135";s:10:"movie_imdb";s:3:"7.7";s:13:"movie_gallery";s:29:"1347,1348,1349,1350,1351,1352";}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [movie_release] => 2020-01-10 [movie_duration] => 135 [movie_imdb] => 7.7 [movie_gallery] => 1347,1348,1349,1350,1351,1352 )
```

Comment: try to unserialize from backend rather than JavaScript (For PHP : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227388/unserialize-php-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Or try this lib: https://github.com/bd808/php-unserialize-js